# is there an method that makes Dynamic length matrix on tensorflow framework by numpy?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to make guided attention loss term by using TensorFlow.
In my case, I code it in encoder.py
In that situation, I have to make dynamic length weight matrix.
But in my code, the shape of matrix is tensor. So I know that in running time.

The making guided attention loss step is:

1. stack attention alignment
2. make guide loss map (likes stack attention alignment shape)
3. element-wise two matrix and get mean loss

So I make below code using TensorFlow and NumPy.

```
self.guide_loss = self._make_guide_loss(states=self._video_encoder_final_state,
                            width_length=self._video_inputs_len,
                            height_length=self._audio_inputs_len,
                            _sigma=0.4
                            )
```

`self._video_inputs_len` & `self._audio_inputs_len` is tensor

```
def _make_guide_loss(self, states, width_length, height_length, _sigma=0.4):
        # If, A->V att. layer loss
        # input - states : self._video_encoder_final_state
        #       - data_lengths : self._audio_inputs_len
        #       - sigma : hparameter (default : 0.4), small sigma makes the narrow attention loss map
        attention_map = states.alignment_history.stack()
        loss_weight = tf.sequence_mask(
                lengths=height_length,
                dtype=self._hparams.dtype,
                )
        guide_map = self._guided_attention_map(max_W=tf.reduce_max(width_length),
                batch_size=self._hparams.batch_size[0 if self._mode == 'train' else 1],
                max_H=tf.reduce_max(height_length),
                sigma=_sigma,
                )
        guide_map_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(guide_map)
        guide_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(attention_map * guide_map))
        guide_loss /= tf.reduce_sum(loss_weight)

        return guide_loss

    def _guided_attention_map(self, max_W, batch_size, max_H, sigma=0.4):    
        # dimension of attention_map : [width, batch_size, height]
        W = np.zeros((max_W, batch_size, max_H), dtype=self._hparams.dtype)
        for batch in range(W.shape[1]):
            for w_pos in range(W.shpae[0]):
                for h_pos in range(W.shape[2]):
                    W[w_pos, batch, h_pos] = 1 - np.exp(-(w_pos / float(max_W) - h_pos / float(max_H)) ** 2 / (2 * g * g))
        return W
```

```
TypeError: _guided_attention_map() got multiple values for argument 'max_W'
```

After add `self` parameter into `_guide_attention_map(self, max_W...)`

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: You are missing the `self` parameter in `_guided_attention_map`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I add self parameter in _guided_attention_map(self, ...) 
But I get the below TypeError.
"TypeError : 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"
What can I do.. T.T